# Spring CSRF protection for login only

Tags: java, spring, csrf

I'm using Spring for a webapplication's backend, and will be using Angular for frontend. I'm trying to use CSRF protection for the login only, following 
[this guide](https://sdqali.in/blog/2016/07/20/csrf-protection-with-spring-security-and-angular-js/) with some modification. What I'm trying to achieve is, that Angular first ajaxing to "/init" which will set the CSRF TOKEN cookie, then it can call the login, which is CSRF protected.

When I'm calling the /init method, it gives back a CSRF token, however after that when I'm calling /login I keep getting 403 forbidden.

Here's the request (using Postman for testing purposes):

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"username":"test","password":"test"}
```

Here's the java code for the csrf:

```
    private RequestMatcher csrfRequestMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {

    private RegexRequestMatcher requestMatcher =
            new RegexRequestMatcher("/login", null);

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return requestMatcher.matches(request);
    }

};
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf()
            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/test/**").authenticated()
            .and().addFilterAt(MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(MyLogoutHandler())
            .and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfGrantingFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
}




public class CsrfGrantingFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) servletRequest.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    String token = csrf.getToken();
    if (token != null && isInit(servletRequest)) {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}

private boolean isInit(ServletRequest servletRequest) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    return request.getRequestURI().equals("/init");
}

@Override
public void destroy() {}
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? Or is just my request bad?

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is enabled by default in Spring, so why is there has to be a requestMatcher, Filter etc? Angular has built in support for CSRF - "XSRF" based on cookies - https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection 
To quote a guide: "Angular wants the cookie name to be "XSRF-TOKEN" and Spring Security provides it as a request attribute by default, so we just need to transfer the value from a request attribute to a cookie."

So to make it work with Angular, in the confgiure() method, configure the csrf() as

```
http.csrf()
     .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
```

Just call /login and after successful login, Angular (assuming Angular 2+) will pick up the token from the cookie and send it

Comment: I want csrf protection only for the /login route this is why i need the requestMatcher. And i'm using the filter for giving back the csrf cookie only for the /init routing. And it gives it back like this:
XSRF-TOKEN: 10ecb6c3-9354-4512-9912-b1f5e093bb80
But i still get forbidden for the /login method with the request i gave above, this is why i dont understand. And i'm not using angular right now, just the Chrome's Postman plugin, for sending http requests.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was fine, but in the header i had to put the token under "X-CSRF-TOKEN" key, not XSRF-TOKEN or CSRF-TOKEN.